# start plink-ssh connection from hta button and pass value to ssh command

Tags: html, ssh, vbscript, hta, plink

I have a little problem with my HTA-vbs script.

This is my VBS script:

```
strInput = UserInput( "USER:" )
pswInput = UserInput( "PSW:" )

Function UserInput( myPrompt )
       UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
End Function

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        objShell.Run "plink.exe &  USER@192.0.0.1 -pw PASSWORD -no-antispoof "myscript.sh"
```

So this is a simple vbs script that launch script in my linux remote machine (I launch this from HTA button). I need only that when I type user and password in a initial textbox, the script save the value and replace USER and PASSWORD when launch the ssh connection.

Is it possible?

Thank you so much. BYE!
Angelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim sUserName
Dim sPassword
Dim objShell
Dim sCommand

sUserName = InputBox("USER:")
sPassword = InputBox("PSW:")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

sCommand = "plink.exe " & sUserName & "@192.0.0.1 -pw " & sPassword & " -no-antispoof ""myscript.sh"""
objShell.Run sCommand
```

You don't need the `UserInput` function, you can call `InputBox` directly.

If you want to save the User Name and Password variables, there are ways to do that also, and you can have them be pre-populated in your `InputBox`:

```
' Set default values or perhaps read these from the Registry
sUserName = "admin"
sPassword = "password"

sUserName = InputBox("USER:", "Remote Connection", sUserName)
sPassword = InputBox("PSW:", "Remote Connection", sPassword)
```